# What is contiguous subarray

Tags: arrays

I am trying to study contiguous subarray but I am not getting any study material which explains this concept.

But I found one example with says that 
Given the array [-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4] the contiguous subarray is [4,-1,2,1]

Can anyone explain on what bases they are saying contiguous subarray is [4,-1,2,1]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It isn't *the* contiguous subarray, there are many. It's just a subsequence without skipping any elements. E.g. [-2, 1], [-2, 1, -3], [2, 1, -5] are all contiguous subarrays of this array, but [2, 1, 4] isn't.

Comment: Still not very clear.  Subarray = "any part or section of an array", contiguous  = "sharing a common border; touching". Is contiguous referring to the array indices or the values?  Please explain what exactly is contiguous about the three subarrays you supplied.

Comment: @Geordie To the indices. I am not sure how to make it clearer than "a subsequence without skipping any elements".

Comment: There's a larger thread on my answer over on comp sci: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/43303/what-is-a-contiguous-subarray/149711?noredirect=1#comment313804_149711
I'll write up more in an answer here

Answer (score 8):

A contiguous subarray is simply a subarray of an array with a condition that the elements of the subarray should be in exact sequence as the sequence of the elements in the array.
for example if the array is [1,2,3,4,5]
then [1,3,5] is a subarray of the array, but not a contiguous subarray since the sequence does not match as the elements 2 and 4 are skipped.
[1,2,3] will be one of the contiguous subarrays.

Answer (score 4):

Note: So I kept my original answer and extra thoughts here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/43303/what-is-a-contiguous-subarray/149711?noredirect=1#comment313804_149711

The actual definition of contiguous subarray (as others have answered) is any sub series of elements in a given array that are contiguous ie their indices are continuous.

So given [1,2,3,4,5,6]:

[1,2,3], [3,4], [3,4,5,6] are all valid contiguous subarrays. **Any algorithm can be used to generate the subarrays.**

Personal note: What was confusing for me was most explanations either use or reference a specific problem or condition set to generate the subarrays. Most don't specifically state there's no direct relationship between the problem and the definition of contiguous subarrays.

For me it's the same as asking:

Q: "What does + do?"

A: "4+4=8"

Me: "OK, so I can only use + with 4, got it."

On my travels I'd see answers like this:

> basically the sum of contiguous array must be greater, if you will try to add the all elements of array it will give you lowest sum, but if you will add this specific range in continuity you will get the greatest sum we can make out of this array.

Which is referring to some specific problem that uses contiguous subarrays, but no one was calling this out, so to a noob you could infer that contiguous subarrays has some further meaning.

This is how my brain worked to grok the definition, so hopefully it helps someone else out.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. These aren't "conditions of what makes a subarrary contiguous"; instead, the subarrays must be contiguous (in the sense described in my answer or https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/43305) _and_ satisfy some additional conditions.

Answer (score 1):

To get it fast:

Any subarray sliced out from a given array [0,...,n] keeping original continuous order of elements in it.

Which starts at element with chosen index between 0 and n-1
and ends at other chosen element of a higher index than the starting one.

Containing all elements of indexes in the chosen range.

[-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4] is indexed [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
[4,-1,2,1] is a contiguous subarray being a range indexed: [3,...,6]

Answer (score 0):

There might be better solution but I am giving here the detailed breakdown solution

```
let a=[-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4];

let sum=0;
let maxLen=0;
let subArr=[];
for(let i=0;i<a.length;i++){
  let temp=a[i];
  let len=1;
  let tempArr=[a[i]];
  for(let j=i+1;j<a.length;j++){
    temp+=a[j]
    len=len+1
    tempArr.push(a[j])
    if(temp>sum){
      sum=temp
      maxLen=len
     subArr=[...tempArr]
 }
 }
 }

console.log(sum,maxLen,subArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Contiguity: All elements in the subarray [4, -1, 2, 1] are adjacent to each other in the original array. There are no elements between them. This means they are contiguous or consecutive within the array.

Sum: The sum of elements in the contiguous subarray [4, -1, 2, 1] is maximized compared to any other contiguous subarray within the given array [-2, 1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5, 4]. In this case, the sum of [4, -1, 2, 1] is 4 + (-1) + 2 + 1 = 6, which is the maximum sum among all possible contiguous subarrays in the given array.

In algorithms and problem-solving contexts, finding the contiguous subarray with the maximum (or minimum) sum is a common problem known as the Maximum Subarray Problem. The contiguous subarray with the maximum sum is also referred to as the "maximum sum subarray" or simply the "contiguous subarray with maximum sum".

Answer (score -4):

basically the sum of contiguous array must be greater, if you will try to add the all elements of array it will give you lowest sum, but if you will add this specific range in continuity you will get the greatest sum we can make out of this array.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).